# Каким образом Release проглатывает исключения

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть код следующий код.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestObject {
public:
    TestObject() : st("default") { cout << st << " is created" << endl; }
    TestObject(const string& s) : st(s) { cout << st << " is created" << endl; }
    string ToString() { return st; }
    void Print() { cout << st << "... printed itself" << endl; }
    ~TestObject() { cout << st << " is destroyed" << endl; }
private:
    string st;
public:
    static TestObject& null() {
        static TestObject to("null");
        return to;
    }
};

TestObject& test() 
{
    TestObject to("Local");
    return to;
    return TestObject::null();
}

int main() 
{
    test().Print();
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Если запустить этот код в режиме Debug, то возникает ошибка, что и понятно, так как функция возвращает ссылку на локальный объект.

Однако если запустить в режиме Release, то все работает и получается следующий вывод:

```
Local is created
Local is destroyed
... printed itself

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Что немного странно.

Кроме того, если вызвать `test().Print();` дважды подряд, то уже на первом вызове будет сгенерировано исключение и программа остановится.

Я имел несчастье допустить подобную ошибку в реальном проекте, и, собрав программу под Release, я потом очень долго гадал, почему функция возвращает пустое значение по умолчанию, которое как я выяснил в данном примере таковым вообще не является. Под отладчиком в Release вызывается будто бы `return TestObject::null();`, хотя печатается не null, а просто пустая строка.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что именно происходит в режиме Release.

---

По совету @Harry запустил следующий код:

```
TestObject &t = test();
TestObject::null().Print();
t.Print();
```

Сначала, вывелось много бреда и начали генерироваться отрывистые звуки "пи, пи, пи", после чего VS остановила работу программы с ошибкой чтения чужой памяти, но звук прекратился, только когда нажал "Прервать". Все последующие попытки запустить код заканчивались остановкой программы со следующим выводом.

```
Local is created
Local is destroyed
null is created
null... printed itself
|√& √*Ф ·в┬│    L√& j3╪u р¤~М√& ☻Щлw р¤~`Я·k         р¤~            X√&         
┼Xпw╠вv∟    д√& ╒Шлw°$Ф  р¤~                °$Ф  р¤~
```

Comment: Какого типа исключения вы ожидаете?

Comment: `Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0F9165F6 (msvcp140d.dll) в ModernTests.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xCCCCCCCC.` - вот это. То что происходит при Debug или если вызвать `test().Print();` дважды подряд

Comment: Нарушение прав доступа не является выбрасываемым исключением, оно только ловится в отладочном режиме потому что там поставлено что такие типы ошибок должны ловиться дебаггером. Попробуйте поставить флаг компиляции на /EHa.

Comment: Функция вернула адрес, указывающий на освобожденную память. Как и когда эта память будет перезаписана, заранее неизвестно. Release-у повезло, он смог прочитать строку. Debug может вообще затирать освобождаемую память нулями.

Comment: @Igor, он считал откуда то пустую строку, а не строку "Local"

Comment: Это не противоречит тому, что я написал. Что такое пустая строка? \0

Comment: @DanielProtopopov а что же происходит в Release когда программа обращается не в свою память?

Comment: То же самое что и при segmentation fault - исключение на уровне железа, так сказать. Его не поймаешь обычным try-catch. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612444/catch-a-memory-access-violation-in-c)

Comment: @RussCoder: Что такое "не своя память"? От того, что память в стеке или в хипе была освобождена на уровне языка/стандартной библиотеки совсем не следует (*в большинстве случаев* не следует), что эта память была возвращена системе и стала "не своей" для вашей программы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам просто не везет :)  Например, адрес, по которому лежал локальный объект, оказался еще не затерт, вот и все. Но, заметьте - строка `st` уже уничтожена, так что выводится просто

```
... printed itself
```

а не

```
Local... printed itself
```

Просто в режиме Release уже не выполняются никакие проверки (на то он и Release, чтоб не тратить время и ресурсы на какие-то лишние проверки) - программа считается отлаженной. А исключение при таком неопределенном поведении генерироваться вовсе не обязано.

Попробуйте интереса ради вклинить еще один вызов - например, так:

```
TestObject &t = test();
TestObject::null().Print();
t.Print();
```

Думаю, будет более интересно. Что именно будет - предсказать невозможно :)

Comment: Попробовал Ваш код. Получился интересный результат, особенно после первого запуска. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну так стек испорчен вызовом. Теперь при обращении к месту, где была строка `st`, там уже лежит не пойми что, и там, где был указатель на данные в `st`, теперь указатель куда-то. И это куда-то и выводится на консоль, а писк - вывод символа c кодом 7, кажется - который звук должен выводить (`\b`)... Словом, что и требовалось показать :)

Answer (score 5):

Ваша программа вызывает классическое неопределенное поведение. Причем не какое-то концептуальное, а совершенно реальное и практически непредсказуемое. Почему вас удивляет, что проявления этого поведения отличаются в отладочной и релизной версии кода?

(У меня, например, в VS2015 отладочная версия вашего кода не выкидывает никакой ошибки, а просто "ломает" `cout` при вызове `Print()`, после чего он вообще отказывается что-либо выводить.)

То, что релизный код (как ваш собственный, так и код стандартной библиотеки) будет радикально отличаться от дебажного из-за одних только оптимизаций, я надеюсь, объяснять не надо. А уж каким этот релизный код получится зависит от стольких труднопредсказуемых переменных, что пытаться искать тут какие-то детерминистские объяснения - пустая трата времени.

Также не ясно, о каком "проглатывании исключения" вы ведете речь. Никаких исключений в этом коде нет.